# Is there a "list all files" procedure in scheme?

Tags: list, racket, librarian

Is there a racket/scheme procedure that returns a list (or vector) of the names of all *user accesible* files?
The output needs to be  a list or vector for applying a "filter", like so:

`(filter pred list-of-all-files)`

The intended application is a text-based, user-friendly "librarian" program.

Comment: Are you asking for something like the shell command `ls` (limited to a specific directory) but filtered to be only files that the user can read or something more like a list of _every single file_ on-disk that the user can read?

Comment: I was looking  for the latter, but in the former, do you mean terminal shell or racket shell? I haven't of `ls` before now.

Comment: I was referring to shells like Windows CMD or unix's bash

Comment: oh...well I'm going to it a program...so no.not really

Answer (score 4):

The relevant procedures you are looking for are [directory-list](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=in-directory#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._directory-list%29%29) and [in-directory](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-directory#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-directory%29%29).

Using `directory-list`, you can retrieve a list of all files and directories in the directory specified by some path (similar to the shell command `ls`).

```
;; ls /some/path
(directory-list "/some/path")
```

On the other hand, `in-directory` returns a sequence that produces **all** of the paths for files, directories, and links within a directory, traversing nested subdirectories recursively (which seems to be what you are primarily looking for).

For example, to return the names of all user readable files and directories under `"/some/path"`, you can do:

```
(for/list ([f (in-directory "/some/path"
                            (lambda (p)
                              (member 'read (file-or-directory-permissions p))))])
  f)
```

You can use [path->string](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html?q=list%20files#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._path-%7E3estring%29%29) to produce the file names in string format instead. So, to create your `list-all-files` procedure:

```
(define (list-all-files path)
  (define (user-readable? f)
    (member 'read (file-or-directory-permissions f)))
  (for/list ([f (in-directory path user-readable?)])
    (path->string f)))
```

Then, you can `filter` the generated list using any predicate `pred`:

```
(filter pred (list-all-files "/some/path"))
```

Comment: There might be a built-in function that does this better, but one could use that example with `in-directory` along with a recursive utility function to traverse the directory tree. This might be closer to what @Flowerfist.rkt is looking for